# Запрос MYSQL связка с таблицей по условию

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите - у меня есть табличка в которой есть  поле "код операции" , "код дебет счета", "код кредит счета". Вот можно ли как-то составить запрос что бы в зависимости от значения поля код операции выбирались значения по код счета из разных таблиц? Или это может вообще решается какими-то другими способами.
Если код операции 1 - то счет берем через Join из одной таблицы если 2 то из другой таблицы

Comment: по left join клеите обе вторичные таблицы и в списке выборки с помощью ifnull или case разруливаете какие из значений брать

Comment: Два запроса, один join с таблицей для операции номер 1, другой join с таблицей для операции номер 2 объединяются в один запрос с помощью волшебного слова `UNION` между двумя этими запросами. При условии, что запросы эти выдают одинаковые поля

Comment: Спасибо.Поля одинаковые выдают.  UNION не пользовался еще - поизучаю. А что быстрее будет один запрос с CASE или цепочка с UNION?

Comment: Можно не использовать case, а вставлять в запись поля из join таблиц в определённом порядке. В программе-получателе смотреть на код операции. Если он равен 1, то данные брать из колонки допустим 3, А если код равен 2, то из колонки 4.

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант - выбираем по максимуму, а отображаем только то что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: А как быть если оба поля "код дебет счета(users.user_login)" и "код кредит счета(accounts.name)"  будут из одной таблицы браться?  Вот пример моего запроса для разных таблиц:    
 SELECT  users.user_login, accounts.name from transactions JOIN users ON transactions.credit_from=users.user_id JOIN accounts ON transactions.debet_to = accounts.id; использовать два JOIN для приклейки одной таблицы поскольку два поля с ней связаны?